# Prove if $n^2$ is even, then $n$ is even

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I'm learning math and it is assumed that $ n^2 $ is even then I have to prove that $n$ is also even ( n is an integer number ).

I searched online and people were suggesting to prove the other way around which means that if you were to assume that $ n $ is odd and $ n^2 $ is odd then you proved your original one which made no sense. Can someone please elaborate on this and what is the best way to prove that ?

Comment: Do you know how to write an even number?

Comment: You can write an odd number as $2k+1$ where $k$ is an integer.

Comment: you can write an even number by n= 2m. Right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To prove $P \implies Q$ you can prove $\sim Q \implies \sim P$ - not $Q$ implies not $P$. This is called contraposition. Both statements are equivalent. Here's how we prove the contrapositive.

Let $n = 2j +1$. Squaring gives $n^2 = 4j^2 + 4j + 1 = 2(2j^2 + 2j) +1$. Hence $n^2$ is odd.

This is easier than proving that if $n^2$ is even then $n$ is even.

Comment: oohh so i don't even need to prove n is even, but I can simply use some logic and math to prove that opposite which will automatically prove what I wanted?

Comment: This proves that indeed $n$ is even if its square is even. If we say two statements are equivalent, then they are the "same." I suggest reading on propositional logic, perhaps from a book on writing proofs, to understand this better.

Comment: one last question, wouldn't that be the same as proving " the product of two odd numbers is odd"? because you write here m,n are integers and m=2q +1 and n = 2r +1 and then eventually ending up with 2(2qr+q+r) +1 ? is this the same prove or am i hallucinating?

Comment: Define "same." Here's a sketch: take two odd numbers and multiply. Can you write the product as $2j+1$? I won't provide details. If you want a proof verification, attempt it and pose that as another question with the "proof-verification" tag.

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I don't have a similar question but i just wanted to make sure that I understood and while writing it down it appeared to me that what we did here is actually the same as proving what I just said above. I got lost again because of non-proving what the actual thing is but instead proving something else, where you can conclude from that it is the same.

Comment: From my answer: "This is called contraposition. Both statements are equivalent." If you prove one statement and know that it's equivalent to another, you're done. The question you pose about "odd times odd is odd" is independent of this, as the direct approach is cleaner. You'll learn in proof-writing that some approaches are faster than others. Sometimes direct proofs are fast, other times, indirect proofs get the job done.

Comment: @SeanRoberson modus tollens is not available in intuitionistic logic

Answer (score 14):

### Definitions

1. $x\text{ is even} := \exists y[y+y=x]$ (Denote as $E(x)$)
2. $x\text{ is odd} := \exists y[S(y+y)=x]$ (Denote as $O(x)$)

### Axioms

1. $\forall x[S(x) \ne 0]$
2. $\forall x \forall y[S(x)=S(y) \implies x=y]$
3. $\forall x[x+0=x]$
4. $\forall x \forall y[x+S(y)=S(x+y)]$
5. $[\varphi(0) \land [\forall x[\varphi(x) \implies \varphi(S(x))]]] \implies [\forall x \varphi(x)]$
6. $\forall x[x*0=0]$
7. $\forall x\forall y[x*S(y)=(x*y)+x]$

### Part 1: Addition is commutative

Let $\varphi(y)$ denote $\forall x[y+x=x+y]$.

Let $\psi a(y)$ denote $a+y=y+a$.

```
01. 0+0=0+0                                         =
02. ψ0(0)                                           ψdef 01
  03. ψ0(b)                                         assumption
  04. 0+b=b+0                                       ψdef 03
  05. S(0+b)=S(b+0)                                 = 04
  06. 0+S(b)=S(b+0)                                 A4
  07. 0+S(b)=S(b)                                   A3
  08. 0+S(b)=S(b)+0                                 A3
  09. ψ0(S(b))                                      ψdef 08
10. ψ0(b)→ψ0(S(b))                                  →I 03-09
11. ∀x[ψ0(x)→ψ0(S(x))]                              ∀I 10
12. [ψ0(0)]∧[∀x[ψ0(x)→ψ0(S(x))]]                    ∧I 02 12
13. [[ψ0(0)]∧[∀x[ψ0(x)→ψ0(S(x))]]]→[∀xψ0(x)]        A5
14. ∀xψ0(x)                                         MP 12 13
15. ∀x[0+x=x+0]                                     ψdef 14
16. ϕ(0)                                            ϕdef 15
  17. ϕ(b)                                          assumption
  18. ∀x[b+x=x+b]                                   ϕdef 17
  19. 0+S(b)=S(b)+0                                 ∀E 15
  20. ψSb(0)                                        ψdef 19
    21. ψSb(a)                                      assumption
    22. S(b)+a=a+S(b)                               ψdef 21
    23. S(b)+S(a)=S(S(b)+a)                         A4
    24. S(b)+S(a)=S(a+S(b))                         para 23 22
    25. S(b)+S(a)=S(S(a+b))                         A4 24
    26. b+a=a+b                                     ∀E 18
    27. S(b)+S(a)=S(S(b+a))                         para 25 26
    28. S(b)+S(a)=S(b+S(a))                         A4 27
    29. b+S(a)=S(a)+b                               ∀E 18
    30. S(b)+S(a)=S(S(a)+b)                         para 28 29
    31. S(b)+S(a)=S(a)+S(b)                         A4 30
    32. ψSb(S(a))                                   ψdef 31
  33. ψSb(a)→ψSb(S(a))                              →I 21-32
  34. ∀x[ψSb(x)→ψSb(S(x))]                          ∀I 33
  35. [ψSb(0)]∧[∀x[ψSb(x)→ψSb(S(x))]]               ∧I 20 34
  36. [[ψSb(0)]∧[∀x[ψSb(x)→ψSb(S(x))]]]→[∀xψSb(x)]  A5
  37. ∀xψSb(x)                                      MP 36 35
  38. ϕ(S(b))                                       ϕdef 37
39. ϕ(b)→ϕ(S(b))                                    →I 17-38
40. ∀x[ϕ(x)→ϕ(S(x))]                                ∀I 39
41. [ϕ(0)]∧[∀x[ϕ(x)→ϕ(S(x))]]                       ∧I 16 40
42. [[ϕ(0)]∧[∀x[ϕ(x)→ϕ(S(x))]]]→[∀xϕ(x)]            A5
43. ∀xϕ(x)                                          MP 42 41
```

We shall use $P1$ to denote this.

### Part 2: Addition is associative

Let $\varphi(x)$ denote $(a+b)+x=a+(b+x)$.

```
01. (a+b)+0=a+b                           A3
02. b+0=b                                 A3
03. (a+b)+0=a+(b+0)                       para 01 02
04. ϕ(0)                                  ϕdef 03
  05. ϕ(c)                                assumption
  06. (a+b)+c=a+(b+c)                     ϕdef 05
  07. S((a+b)+c)=S(a+(b+c))               = 06
  08. (a+b)+S(c)=S(a+(b+c))               A4 07
  09. (a+b)+S(c)=a+S(b+c)                 A4 08
  10. (a+b)+S(c)=a+(b+S(c))               A4 09
  11. ϕ(S(c))                             ϕdef 10
12. ϕ(c)→ϕ(S(c))                          →I 05-11
13. ∀x[ϕ(x)→ϕ(S(x))]                      ∀I 12
14. [ϕ(0)]∧[∀x[ϕ(x)→ϕ(S(x))]]             ∧I 04 13
15. [[ϕ(0)]∧[∀x[ϕ(x)→ϕ(S(x))]]]→[∀xϕ(x)]  A5
16. ∀xϕ(x)                                MP 15 14
```

We shall use $P2$ to denote this.

### Part 3: Multiplication is left-distributive

Let $\varphi(x)$ denote $a*(b+x)=(a*b)+(a*x)$.

```
01. b+0=b                                 A3
02. a*(b+0)=a*b                           = 01
03. a*0=0                                 A6
04. (a*b)+0=a*b                           A3
05. (a*b)+(a*0)=a*b                       para 04 03
06. a*(b+0)=(a*b)+(a*0)                   para 02 05
07. ϕ(0)                                  ϕdef 06
  08. ϕ(c)                                assumption
  09. a*(b+c)=(a*b)+(a*c)                 ϕdef 08
  10. b+S(c)=S(b+c)                       A4
  11. a*(b+S(c))=a*S(b+c)                 = 10
  12. a*(S(b+c))=(a*(b+c))+a              A7
  13. a*(b+S(c))=(a*(b+c))+a              para 11 12
  14. a*(b+S(c))=((a*b)+(a*c))+a          para 13 09
  15. (a*b)+(a*c))+a=(a*b)+((a*c)+a)      P2
  16. a*(b+S(c))=(a*b)+((a*c)+a)          para 14 15
  17. a*S(c)=(a*c)+a                      A7
  18. a*(b+S(c))=(a*b)+(a*S(c))           para 16 17
  19. ϕ(S(c))                             ϕdef 18
20. ϕ(c)→ϕ(S(c))                          →I 08-19
21. ∀x[ϕ(x)→ϕ(S(x))]                      ∀I 20
22. [ϕ(0)]∧[∀x[ϕ(x)→ϕ(S(x))]]             ∧I 07 21
23. [[ϕ(0)]∧[∀x[ϕ(x)→ϕ(S(x))]]]→[∀xϕ(x)]  A5
24. ∀xϕ(x)                                MP 23 22
```

We shall use $P3$ to denote this.

### Part 4: Every non-zero number has a predecessor

Let $\varphi(x)$ denote $x \ne 0 \implies \exists y [S(y)=x]$.

```
  01. 0≠0                                 assumption
  02. ⊥                                   01
  03. Ǝy[S(y)=0]                          explosion
04. 0≠0→Ǝy[S(y)=0]                        →I 01-03
05. ϕ(0)                                  ϕdef 04
  06. ϕ(a)                                assumption
  07. a≠0→Ǝy[S(y)=a]                      ϕdef 06
    08. S(a)≠0                            assumption
    09. S(a)=S(a)                         =
    10. Ǝy[S(y)=S(a)]                     ƎI 09
  10. S(a)≠0→Ǝy[S(y)=S(a)]                →I 08-10
  11. ϕ(S(a))                             ϕdef 10
12. ϕ(a)→ϕ(S(a))                          →I 06-11
13. ∀x[ϕ(x)→ϕ(S(x))]                      ∀I 12
14. [ϕ(0)]∧[∀x[ϕ(x)→ϕ(S(x))]]             ∧I 05 13
15. [[ϕ(0)]∧[∀x[ϕ(x)→ϕ(S(x))]]]→[∀xϕ(x)]  A5
16. ∀xϕ(x)                                MP 15 14
```

We shall use $P4$ to denote this.

### Part 5: Every number is either odd or even

Let $\varphi(x)$ denote $[E(x) \land \neg O(x)] \lor [O(x) \land \neg E(x)]$.

```
01. 0+0=0                                      A3
02. Ǝy[y+y=0]                                  ƎI 01
03. E(0)                                       Edef 02
  04. O(0)                                     assumption
  05. Ǝy[S(y+y)=0]                             Odef 04
    06. S(b+b)=0                               assumption
    07. ⊥                                      A1
  08. ⊥                                        ƎE 05 06-07
09. ¬O(0)                                      ¬I 04-08
10. E(0)∧¬O(0)                                 ∧I 03 09
11. [E(0)∧¬O(0)]∨[O(0)∧¬E(0)]                  vI 10
12. ϕ(0)                                       ϕdef 11
  13. ϕ(a)                                     assumption
  14. [E(a)∧¬O(a)]∨[O(a)∧¬E(a)]                ϕdef 13
    15. E(a)∧¬O(a)                             assumption
    16. E(a)                                   ∧E 15
    17. ∃y[y+y=a]                              Edef 16
      18. b+b=a                                assumption
      19. S(b+b)=S(a)                          18
      20. ∃y[S(y+y)=S(a)]                      ∃I 19
    21. ∃y[S(y+y)=S(a)]                        ∃E 17 18-20
    22. O(S(a))                                Odef 21
      23. E(S(a))                              assumption
      24. ∃y[y+y=S(a)]                         Edef 23
        25. b+b=S(a)                           assumption
          26. b=0                              assumption
          27. 0+0=S(a)                         para 25 26
          28. 0=S(a)                           A3 27
          29. ⊥                                A1
        30. b≠0                                ¬I 26-29
        31. ∃z[S(z)=b]                         P4 30
          32. S(c)=b                           assumption
          33. S(c)+S(c)=S(a)                   para 25 32
          34. S(S(c)+c)=S(a)                   A4 33
          35. S(c)+c=a                         A2 34
          36. c+S(c)=a                         P1 35
          37. S(c+c)=a                         A4 36
          38. ∃y[S(y+y)=a]                     ∃I 37
          39. ¬O(a)                            ∧E 15
          40. ⊥                                38 39
        41. ⊥                                  ∃E 31 32-40
      42. ⊥                                    ∃E 24 25-41
    43. ¬E(S(a))                               ¬I 23-43
    44. O(S(a))∧¬E(S(a))                       ∧I 22 43
    45. [E(S(a))∧¬O(S(a))]∨[O(S(a))∧¬E(S(a))]  ∨I 44
    46. ϕ(S(a))                                ϕdef 45
  47. [E(a)∧¬O(a)]→ϕ(S(a))                     →I 15-46
    48. O(a)∧¬E(a)                             assumption
    49. O(a)                                   ∧E 48
    50. ∃y[S(y+y)=a]                           Odef 49
      51. S(b+b)=a                             assumption
      52. S(S(b+b))=S(a)                       = 51
      53. S(b+S(b))=S(a)                       A4 52
      54. S(S(b)+b)=S(a)                       P1 53
      55. S(b)+S(b)=S(a)                       A4 54
      56. ∃y[y+y=S(a)]                         ∃I 55
    57. ∃y[y+y=S(a)]                           ∃E 50 51-56
    58. E(S(a))                                Edef 57
      59. O(S(a))                              assumption
      60. ∃y[S(y+y)=S(a)]                      Odef 59
        61. S(b+b)=S(a)                        assumption
        62. b+b=a                              A2 61
        63. ∃y[y+y=a]                          ∃I 62
        64. ¬E(a)                              ∧E 48
        65. ⊥                                  63 64
      66. ⊥                                    ∃E 60 61-65
    67. ¬O(S(a))                               ¬I 59-66
    68. E(S(a))∧¬O(S(a))                       ∧I 58 67
    69. [E(S(a))∧¬O(S(a))]∨[O(S(a))∧¬E(S(a))]  ∨I 68
    70. ϕ(S(a))                                ϕdef 69
  71. [O(a)∧¬E(a)]→ϕ(S(a))                     →I 48-70
  72. ϕ(S(a))                                  ∨E 14 47 71
73. ϕ(a)→ϕ(S(a))                               →I 48-72
74. ∀x[ϕ(x)→ϕ(S(x))]                           ∀I 73
75. [ϕ(0)]∧[∀x[ϕ(x)→ϕ(S(x))]]                  ∧I 12 74
76. [[ϕ(0)]∧[∀x[ϕ(x)→ϕ(S(x))]]]→[∀xϕ(x)]       A5
77. ∀xϕ(x)                                     MP 76 75
```

We shall use $P5$ to denote this.

### Part 6: If $n^2$ is even then $n$ is even

```
  01. E(n*n)                                                   assumption
  02. ∃y[y+y=n*n]                                              Edef 01
  03. [E(n)∧¬O(n)]∨[O(n)∧¬E(n)]                                P5 n
    04. E(n)∧¬O(n)                                             assumption
    05. E(n)                                                   ∧E 04
  06. [E(n)∧¬O(n)]→E(n)                                        →I 04-05
    07. O(n)∧¬E(n)                                             assumption
    08. O(n)                                                   ∧E 07
    09. ∃y[S(y+y)=n]                                           Odef 08
      10. S(b+b)=n                                             assumption
      11. S(b+b)*S(b+b)=n*n                                    = 10
      12. (S(b+b)*(b+b))+S(b+b)=n*n                            A7 11
      13. (S(b+b)*((b+0)+b))+S(b+b)=n*n                        A3 12
      14. (S(b+b)*((0+b)+b))+S(b+b)=n*n                        P1 13
      15. (S(b+b)*(((b*0)+b)+b))+S(b+b)=n*n                    A6 14
      16. (S(b+b)*((b*S(0))+b))+S(b+b)=n*n                     A7 15
      17. (S(b+b)*(b*S(S(0))))+S(b+b)=n*n                      A7 16
      18. ((S(b+b)*b)*S(S(0)))+S(b+b)=n*n                      P3 17
      19. (((S(b+b)*b)*S(0))+(S(b+b)*b))+S(b+b)=n*n            A7 18
      20. ((((S(b+b)*b)*0)+(S(b+b)*b))+(S(b+b)*b))+S(b+b)=n*n  A7 19
      21. ((0+(S(b+b)*b))+(S(b+b)*b))+S(b+b)=n*n               A6 20
      22. (((S(b+b)*b)+0)+(S(b+b)*b))+S(b+b)=n*n               P1 21
      23. ((S(b+b)*b)+(S(b+b)*b))+S(b+b)=n*n                   A3 22
      24. S(((S(b+b)*b)+(S(b+b)*b))+(b+b))=n*n                 A4 23
      25. S((((S(b+b)*b)+(S(b+b)*b))+b)+b)=n*n                 P2 24
      26. S(((S(b+b)*b)+((S(b+b)*b)+b))+b)=n*n                 P2 25
      27. S(((S(b+b)*b)+(b+(S(b+b)*b)))+b)=n*n                 P1 26
      28. S((((S(b+b)*b)+b+(S(b+b)*b)))+b)=n*n                 P2 27
      29. S((((S(b+b)*b)+b)+((S(b+b)*b))+b))=n*n               P2 28
      30. ∃y[S(c+c)=n*n]                                       ∃I 29
    31. ∃y[S(c+c)=n*n]                                         ∃E 09 10-30
    32. O(n*n)                                                 Edef 31
    33. [E(n*n)∧¬O(n*n)]∨[O(n*n)∧¬E(n*n)]                      P5 n*n
      34. E(n*n)∧¬O(n*n)                                       assumption
      35. ¬O(n*n)                                              ∧E 34
      36. ⊥                                                    31 35
    37. [E(n*n)∧¬O(n*n)]→⊥                                     →I 34-36
      38. O(n*n)∧¬E(n*n)                                       assumption
      39. ¬E(n*n)                                              ∧E 38
      40. ⊥                                                    01 39
    41. [O(n*n)∧¬E(n*n)]→⊥                                     →I 38-40
    42. ⊥                                                      ∨E 33 37 41
    43. E(n)                                                   explosion
  44. [O(n)∧¬E(n)]→E(n)                                        →I 07-43
  45. E(n)                                                     ∨E 03 06 44
46. E(n*n)→E(n)                                                →I 01-45
```

### Conclusion

This is surprisingly provable in intuitionistic logic.

Comment: I really think this is overkill for what the OP asks.

Comment: This is amazing. 10 outta 10

Comment: Please tell which language it is, so as to make better out of it.

Comment: Please don't tell me you did this by hand.

Comment: I did this by hand.

Answer (score 2):

**Lemma:** Let $m, n \in \Bbb Z$. If $m+n$ is even, then $m$ has the same parity as $n$.

*Proof:* Suppose by contradiction, without loss of generality, that $m$ and $n$ have different parities. Therefore $m = 2a$ and $n = 2b + 1$. So $2|2(a+b) + 1 \implies 2|1$, absurd. Therefore $m$ and $n$ have the same parities.

Now see that $n^2 - n = n(n-1)$, product of two consecutive numbers. So $n^2$ and $-n$ have the same parity (the product is even, analyze the remainder for each case) . Therefore $-n$ is even so $n$ is also even.

Comment: Best and unique.